# Minimum time to write all memory of DDR3 (micron)

Tags: ddr3

I have a 1GB DDR3 memory from micron. Do you know how to calculate the minimum time to write the entire memory consecutively ?

My problem is to know how to include all timing in the bandwidth calculation (banks/rows activation time, pre-charge, ...)

My DDR3 is clocked at 800Mhz -> [MT41K1G8SN-125](https://www.micron.com/parts/dram/ddr3-sdram/mt41k1g8sn-125)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do overlapped burst writes to all of the banks in sequence, it's possible to get about 80-90% of the raw data bus bandwidth as useable transfers. Most of the overhead for any given bank is "hidden" behind the data transfers to other banks. This is the approach we use when buffering high-definition video streams, which involves a mix of reads and writes from multiple requestors.

With a 16-bit DDR bus running at 800 MHz, you're transferring about 2.6-2.9 GB/s, so you should be able to write the whole thing in less than 0.4 second.

Comment: Thanks, in fact my DDR3 is 8-bits DDR bus then I think I can achieve 0.8 second.